# Detect scheduled tasks with sysmon

Tags: scheduled-tasks, splunk

How can I detect running scheduled tasks with sysmon in splunk?

There is a scheduled task running and I don't know since when it started how can I detect the scheduled task and when it first started?

I know that EventID 106 – stands for "new scheduled job" but is there a event id or something in the message that tells me that a process is comes from a scheduled task?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I know you can check for Logon_Type=4 in Windows Security Logon Events (4624, 4625, 4634) which refer to "Batch / Scheduled Task" related logons.

Do you have the Scheduled Tasks Log being ingested into Splunk inputs.conf?
https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/Data/MonitorWindowseventlogdata#Use_the_.22Full_Name.22_log_property_in_Event_Viewer_to_specify_complex_Event_Log_channel_names_properly